# How to limit div height within browser so no vertical scrolling PLUS fix div contents at base of div/browser window?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been struggling with something I KNOW is not as difficult as I'm making it!

I have this ugly spinning pie (don't ask) and its supposed to be positioned so that it sits at the bottom of the homepage window with only the top half of the pie showing, and the rest hidden - so the center axis should sit at the bottom of the browser window. I'm trying to set this up (1) so that the homepage container div with the bg photo doesn't expand below the visible browser window and does not give a vertical scrollbar, and then have the pie correctly positioned within it so only the top half shows.

Help??

Here's a jsfiddle that's a little messy - the pie doesn't spin but really I just need to work out the placement: http://jsfiddle.net/bwL5bxdf/

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
.home2 {        
    background-image:url(img/001.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height:200px;
    max-width:1200px;
    overflow:none;
    }
body {
     background-image:url(img/curtains.png);
     background-size:cover;
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-position:top center;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     position:relative;
     z-index:-1;
     padding-top:30px;
 }

figure#wheel-wrap {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    top:50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#wheel {
    width: 50%;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
}

#wheel img{      
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
}

#leftarrow {    
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    float:left;
}
#leftarrow img{
   width:100%;
}
#leftarrow:hover{
   cursor: pointer; 
}

#rightarrow {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#rightarrow img{
       width:100%;
}
#rightarrow:hover{
   cursor: pointer; 
}
```

Here's the relevant piece of HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
<div class="home2" style="min-height:500px;">

<figure id="wheel-wrap">
        <div id="leftarrow">
       <img src="http://www.bluetabby.net/rr/img/leftarw.png" width="100%"> 
      </div>
    <div id="wheel">
   <img id="wheel2" src="http://www.bluetabby.net/rr/img/pie.png"  usemap="#Pie" />
  </div>
    <img class="marker" src="http://bluetabby.com/rr/img/marker.png" />
 <div id="rightarrow">
<img src="http://www.bluetabby.net/rr/img/rtarw.png" width="100%"></div>
</figure>

</div>
```

Here's a link if you want to see an appoximation of how its supposed to work (I know its hideous - its not my fault!): http://bluetabby.net/rr/index21.html

Thank you!!

Comment: Can you clarify what you meant by "so that the homepage container div with the bg photo doesn't expand below the visible browser window and does not give a vertical scrollbar, and then have the pie correctly positioned within it so only the top half shows." 1) No vertical scroll bar?, 2) The Pie is only showing the top half at all times?

Comment: I know - its hard to describe - bascially I want the div home2 to extend to the full height of the browser window, and then, I want the div Wheel-wrap to be positioned within it so that the pie is half hidden below the bottom of browser edge (so a hidden overflow of the wheel-wrap) and half above so that what you see is a half-circle sitting upon the bottom of the screen. If its too complicated, I can fake it by doing a bazillion media queries for various heights and widths, was hoping for an elegant solution! Thanks!

Comment: Updated with answer below - I feel like I'm understanding the interaction better but still not 100%.  Let me know. And on a side note the site has some very interesting interactions :)

Comment: @peterdotjs This site! Holy cats - I can't get them to understand the value of usability at all... :)

Answer (score 1):

I've updated you're jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/peterdotjs/m9j6mgp6/

I made a few simple changes which is making me suspect that I still haven't fully grasped the desired interaction.

```
#wheel {
    width: 100%; //changed
    height:auto;
    position:fixed; //changed
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
}

#wheel img{
    left: 0px;
    width: 50%; //changed
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
}
```

@Haikukitty let me know if this is something along the lines of what you were trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks! But yeah, whatever you did doesnt seem to be putting it in the right place either... sorry I'm having such a hard time describing it. Its a stupid layout! So, FYI - I got it pretty close - see here if you want to know what I was trying to say! http://bluetabby.com/rrevents/
I'll still have to manually fix styles for tablet and below, but that's not too bad.

Comment: Sweet! Whatever you did this time - it does seem to be holding its position as its supposed to! I'll try it in the site. Thanks!!